# error message of plugin Jquery Validation does not appear right

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

i have custom Method Jquery vAlidation on my code.

this my code

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("number_space", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^\d{8,}$/.test(value.replace(/\s/g, ''));
        }, "Hanya angka dan spasi yang diperbolehkan");


            jQuery("#quesioner_form").validate({
                errorElement: 'label',
                rules: {
                    responden_phone: {
                        required: true,
                        number_space:true,
                        minlength: 6
                    },                          

                },
                messages: {
                    responden_phone: {
                        required: "Harap isi nomer telepon anda",
                        number_space: "Hanya angka dan spasi yang diperbolehkan",
                        minlength: "Minimal 6 karakter"
                    },
            });
```

update: via http://jsfiddle.net/ykgfy53d/

the code above,"responden_phone" allowed number and space, and must minlength 6 character . But when it's running, error message  does not appear right. when I type **valid number and space** and **not minlengt 6**, error of "Hanya angka dan spasi yang diperbolehkan" not hide until length is more than 5. The right logic is when **valid number and space** and **not minlengt 6**,  error of "Minimal 6 karakter" is show. how to fix it ? sorry for my engglish

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide an example of your code, using JSFiddle or similar.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things preventing your code from working as you expect:

1. Your regular expression is not correct - use `/^[\d ]{8,}$/`, meaning - at least 8 characters that are either digits or a space
2. You are stripping spaces from your string before testing

I've [modified your example](http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/67L2h35z/1/) to work as your expect.

For reference, I changed this:

```
return this.optional(element) || /^\d{8,}$/.test(value.replace(/\s/g, ''));
```

To:

```
return this.optional(element) || /^[\d ]{8,}$/.test(value);
```

Comment: your code not edited sir, but thanks for your answer... i remove "{8,}$" on regex and this work :)